# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file & Out of memory on a ...byte allocation

Tags: java, android, xml

There is a Video-game app and when I test with Samsung N-8010(1024*768) and Galaxy S2(640*480) it works fine however with Note 3(1920*1080) logcat showing me inflating error and out of memory. I read others about this but none of them was helpful. Can someone find my problem and solution ?

I need to cut my xml but in line 212 it's just one of button and each run it's referring one of button in xml

LogCat :

```
02-11 15:30:50.484: E/dalvikvm-heap(15795): Out of memory on a 2250016-byte allocation.
02-11 15:30:50.489: I/dalvikvm(15795): "main" prio=5 tid=1 RUNNABLE
02-11 15:30:50.489: I/dalvikvm(15795):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x417b6578 self=0x417a1648
02-11 15:30:50.489: I/dalvikvm(15795):   | sysTid=15795 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1074192380
02-11 15:30:50.489: I/dalvikvm(15795):   | state=R schedstat=( 662807416 95096167 570 ) utm=36 stm=29 core=2
02-11 15:30:50.489: I/dalvikvm(15795):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
02-11 15:30:50.489: I/dalvikvm(15795):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:596)
02-11 15:30:50.489: I/dalvikvm(15795):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
02-11 15:30:50.489: I/dalvikvm(15795):   at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:832)
02-11 15:30:50.489: I/dalvikvm(15795):   at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2988)
02-11 15:30:50.489: I/dalvikvm(15795):   at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
02-11 15:30:50.489: I/dalvikvm(15795):   at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3563)
02-11 15:30:50.489: I/dalvikvm(15795):   at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:879)
02-11 15:30:50.489: I/dalvikvm(15795):   at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:108)
02-11 15:30:50.489: I/dalvikvm(15795):   at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:104)
02-11 15:30:50.489: I/dalvikvm(15795):   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
02-11 15:30:50.489: I/dalvikvm(15795):   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
02-11 15:30:50.489: I/dalvikvm(15795):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:600)
02-11 15:30:50.489: I/dalvikvm(15795):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
02-11 15:30:50.489: I/dalvikvm(15795):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:675)
02-11 15:30:50.489: I/dalvikvm(15795):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:700)
02-11 15:30:50.489: I/dalvikvm(15795):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
02-11 15:30:50.489: I/dalvikvm(15795):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769)
02-11 15:30:50.489: I/dalvikvm(15795):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769)
02-11 15:30:50.489: I/dalvikvm(15795):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
02-11 15:30:50.489: I/dalvikvm(15795):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
02-11 15:30:50.489: I/dalvikvm(15795):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
02-11 15:30:50.489: I/dalvikvm(15795):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:361)
02-11 15:30:50.489: I/dalvikvm(15795):   at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1956)
02-11 15:30:50.489: I/dalvikvm(15795):   at com.example.anlatbanatest.Categoris.onCreate(Categoris.java:61)
02-11 15:30:50.489: I/dalvikvm(15795):   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5369)
02-11 15:30:50.489: I/dalvikvm(15795):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
02-11 15:30:50.489: I/dalvikvm(15795):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2267)
02-11 15:30:50.489: I/dalvikvm(15795):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2358)
02-11 15:30:50.489: I/dalvikvm(15795):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:165)
02-11 15:30:50.489: I/dalvikvm(15795):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1326)
02-11 15:30:50.489: I/dalvikvm(15795):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-11 15:30:50.489: I/dalvikvm(15795):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-11 15:30:50.489: I/dalvikvm(15795):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5450)
02-11 15:30:50.489: I/dalvikvm(15795):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-11 15:30:50.489: I/dalvikvm(15795):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
02-11 15:30:50.489: I/dalvikvm(15795):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
02-11 15:30:50.489: I/dalvikvm(15795):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
02-11 15:30:50.489: I/dalvikvm(15795):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-11 15:30:50.489: D/skia(15795): --- allocation failed for scaled bitmap
02-11 15:30:50.494: D/AndroidRuntime(15795): Shutting down VM
02-11 15:30:50.494: W/dalvikvm(15795): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x417b5700)
02-11 15:30:50.494: E/AndroidRuntime(15795): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-11 15:30:50.494: E/AndroidRuntime(15795): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.anlatbanatest/com.example.anlatbanatest.Categoris}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #212: Error inflating class <unknown>
02-11 15:30:50.494: E/AndroidRuntime(15795):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2304)
02-11 15:30:50.494: E/AndroidRuntime(15795):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2358)
02-11 15:30:50.494: E/AndroidRuntime(15795):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:165)
02-11 15:30:50.494: E/AndroidRuntime(15795):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1326)
02-11 15:30:50.494: E/AndroidRuntime(15795):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-11 15:30:50.494: E/AndroidRuntime(15795):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-11 15:30:50.494: E/AndroidRuntime(15795):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5450)
02-11 15:30:50.494: E/AndroidRuntime(15795):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-11 15:30:50.494: E/AndroidRuntime(15795):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
02-11 15:30:50.494: E/AndroidRuntime(15795):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
02-11 15:30:50.494: E/AndroidRuntime(15795):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
02-11 15:30:50.494: E/AndroidRuntime(15795):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-11 15:30:50.494: E/AndroidRuntime(15795): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #212: Error inflating class <unknown>
02-11 15:30:50.494: E/AndroidRuntime(15795):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:626)
02-11 15:30:50.494: E/AndroidRuntime(15795):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
02-11 15:30:50.494: E/AndroidRuntime(15795):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:675)
02-11 15:30:50.494: E/AndroidRuntime(15795):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:700)
02-11 15:30:50.494: E/AndroidRuntime(15795):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
02-11 15:30:50.494: E/AndroidRuntime(15795):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769)
02-11 15:30:50.494: E/AndroidRuntime(15795):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769)
02-11 15:30:50.494: E/AndroidRuntime(15795):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
02-11 15:30:50.494: E/AndroidRuntime(15795):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
02-11 15:30:50.494: E/AndroidRuntime(15795):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
02-11 15:30:50.494: E/AndroidRuntime(15795):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:361)
02-11 15:30:50.494: E/AndroidRuntime(15795):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1956)
02-11 15:30:50.494: E/AndroidRuntime(15795):    at com.example.anlatbanatest.Categoris.onCreate(Categoris.java:61)
02-11 15:30:50.494: E/AndroidRuntime(15795):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5369)
02-11 15:30:50.494: E/AndroidRuntime(15795):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
02-11 15:30:50.494: E/AndroidRuntime(15795):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2267)
02-11 15:30:50.494: E/AndroidRuntime(15795):    ... 11 more
02-11 15:30:50.494: E/AndroidRuntime(15795): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
02-11 15:30:50.494: E/AndroidRuntime(15795):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
02-11 15:30:50.494: E/AndroidRuntime(15795):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
02-11 15:30:50.494: E/AndroidRuntime(15795):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:600)
02-11 15:30:50.494: E/AndroidRuntime(15795):    ... 26 more
02-11 15:30:50.494: E/AndroidRuntime(15795): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
02-11 15:30:50.494: E/AndroidRuntime(15795):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
02-11 15:30:50.494: E/AndroidRuntime(15795):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:596)
02-11 15:30:50.494: E/AndroidRuntime(15795):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
02-11 15:30:50.494: E/AndroidRuntime(15795):    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:832)
02-11 15:30:50.494: E/AndroidRuntime(15795):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2988)
02-11 15:30:50.494: E/AndroidRuntime(15795):    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
02-11 15:30:50.494: E/AndroidRuntime(15795):    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3563)
02-11 15:30:50.494: E/AndroidRuntime(15795):    at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:879)
02-11 15:30:50.494: E/AndroidRuntime(15795):    at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:108)
02-11 15:30:50.494: E/AndroidRuntime(15795):    at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:104)
02-11 15:30:50.494: E/AndroidRuntime(15795):    ... 29 more
```

xml :

```
                ....
                ....
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/categories_button_yerli_tarihi_mekanlar"
                android:layout_width="130dp"
                android:layout_height="130dp"
                android:layout_margin="20dp"
                android:background="@drawable/yerli_tarihi_mekanlar" />
                ....
                ....
```

Code :

```
public class Categoris extends Activity {

    private Button help_button;
    private Button expand_button;
    private Button bt_90;
    private Button bt_bilim_teknoloji;
    private Button bt_bitkiler_alemi;
    private Button bt_cizgi_film;
    private Button bt_dizi_yabanci;
    private Button bt_dizi_yerli;
    private Button bt_filmler;
    private Button bt_hayvanlar_alemi;
    private Button bt_masallar_kahramanlar;
    private Button bt_oyunlar;
    private Button bt_sarkicilar_yabanci;
    private Button bt_sarkicilar_yerli;
    private Button bt_sehirler_tr;
    private Button bt_siyasiler;
    private Button bt_sporlar;
    private Button bt_super_kahramanlar;
    private Button bt_tarihi_kisi_yabanci;
    private Button bt_tarihi_kisi_yerli;
    private Button bt_tarihi_mekan_yabanci;
    private Button bt_tarihi_mekan_yerli;
    private Button bt_ulkeler;
    private Button bt_unlu_sehirler;
    private Button bt_unluler;
    private Button bt_yemekler;
    private Button bt_cizgi_film_kahraman;
    private Button bt_karisik;

    boolean doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.categories);

        DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
        int height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
        int width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;;

        Log.i("gen", String.valueOf(width));
        Log.i("yuk", String.valueOf(height));


        help_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.categories_button_help);
        expand_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.categories_button_expand);

        bt_90 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.categories_button_doksanlar);
        bt_bilim_teknoloji = (Button) findViewById(R.id.categories_button_bilim_teknoloji);
        bt_bitkiler_alemi = (Button) findViewById(R.id.categories_button_bitkiler_alemi);
        bt_cizgi_film = (Button) findViewById(R.id.categories_button_cizgi_filmler);
        bt_dizi_yabanci = (Button) findViewById(R.id.categories_button_yabaci_diziler);
        bt_dizi_yerli = (Button) findViewById(R.id.categories_button_yerli_diziler);
        bt_filmler = (Button) findViewById(R.id.categories_button_filmler);
        bt_hayvanlar_alemi = (Button) findViewById(R.id.categories_button_hayvanlar_alemi);
        bt_masallar_kahramanlar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.categories_button_masallar);
        bt_oyunlar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.categories_button_oyunlar);
        bt_sarkicilar_yabanci = (Button) findViewById(R.id.categories_button_yabanci_sarkicilar);
        bt_sarkicilar_yerli = (Button) findViewById(R.id.categories_button_yerli_sarkicilar);
        bt_sehirler_tr = (Button) findViewById(R.id.categories_button_sehirler);
        bt_siyasiler = (Button) findViewById(R.id.categories_button_siyasiler);
        bt_sporlar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.categories_button_sporlar);
        bt_super_kahramanlar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.categories_button_super_kahramanlar);
        bt_tarihi_kisi_yabanci = (Button) findViewById(R.id.categories_button_yabanci_tarihi_kisiler);
        bt_tarihi_kisi_yerli = (Button) findViewById(R.id.categories_button_yerli_tarihi_kisiler);
        bt_tarihi_mekan_yabanci = (Button) findViewById(R.id.categories_button_yabanci_tarihi_mekanlar);
        bt_tarihi_mekan_yerli = (Button) findViewById(R.id.categories_button_yerli_tarihi_mekanlar);
        bt_ulkeler = (Button) findViewById(R.id.categories_button_ulkeler);
        bt_unlu_sehirler = (Button) findViewById(R.id.categories_button_unlu_sehirler);
        bt_unluler = (Button) findViewById(R.id.categories_button_unluler);
        bt_yemekler = (Button) findViewById(R.id.categories_button_yemekler);
        bt_cizgi_film_kahraman = (Button) findViewById(R.id.categories_button_cizgi_film_kahraman);
        bt_karisik = (Button) findViewById(R.id.categories_button_karisik);

        help_button.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
        expand_button.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
        bt_90.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
        bt_bilim_teknoloji.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
        bt_bitkiler_alemi.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
        bt_cizgi_film.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
        bt_dizi_yabanci.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
        bt_dizi_yerli.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
        bt_filmler.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
        bt_hayvanlar_alemi.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
        bt_masallar_kahramanlar.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
        bt_oyunlar.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
        bt_sarkicilar_yabanci.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
        bt_sarkicilar_yerli.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
        bt_sehirler_tr.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
        bt_siyasiler.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
        bt_sporlar.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
        bt_super_kahramanlar.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
        bt_tarihi_kisi_yabanci.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
        bt_tarihi_kisi_yerli.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
        bt_tarihi_mekan_yabanci.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
        bt_tarihi_mekan_yerli.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
        bt_ulkeler.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
        bt_unlu_sehirler.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
        bt_unluler.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
        bt_yemekler.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
        bt_cizgi_film_kahraman.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
        bt_karisik.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);

        ArrayList<Button> button_list = new ArrayList<Button>();

        button_list.add(bt_90);
        button_list.add(bt_bilim_teknoloji);
        button_list.add(bt_bitkiler_alemi);
        button_list.add(bt_cizgi_film);
        button_list.add(bt_dizi_yabanci);
        button_list.add(bt_dizi_yerli);
        button_list.add(bt_filmler);
        button_list.add(bt_hayvanlar_alemi);
        button_list.add(bt_masallar_kahramanlar);
        button_list.add(bt_oyunlar);
        button_list.add(bt_sarkicilar_yabanci);
        button_list.add(bt_sarkicilar_yerli);
        button_list.add(bt_sehirler_tr);
        button_list.add(bt_siyasiler);
        button_list.add(bt_sporlar);
        button_list.add(bt_super_kahramanlar);
        button_list.add(bt_tarihi_kisi_yabanci);
        button_list.add(bt_tarihi_kisi_yerli);
        button_list.add(bt_tarihi_mekan_yabanci);
        button_list.add(bt_tarihi_mekan_yerli);
        button_list.add(bt_ulkeler);
        button_list.add(bt_unlu_sehirler);
        button_list.add(bt_unluler);
        button_list.add(bt_yemekler);
        button_list.add(bt_cizgi_film_kahraman);
        button_list.add(bt_karisik);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp_category = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(((int)(width*0.24)), ((int)(width*0.24)));
        lp_category.setMargins(((int)(width*0.005)), 0, ((int)(width*0.005)), 0);


        for (Button b:button_list) {
//          b.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(((int)(width*0.24)), ((int)(width*0.24))));
            b.setLayoutParams(lp_category);
        }

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp_small_button = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(((int)(height*0.1)), ((int)(height*0.1)));

        lp_small_button.setMargins(0, 0, ((int)(height*0.025)), ((int)(height*0.035)));
        help_button.setLayoutParams(lp_small_button);
        lp_small_button.setMargins(((int)(height*0.025)), 0, 0, ((int)(height*0.035)));
        expand_button.setLayoutParams(lp_small_button);


    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (doubleBackToExitPressedOnce) {
            if (VideoViewTest.videoPath != null) {
                if (Result.isSaved == 0) {
                    File file = new File(VideoViewTest.videoPath);
                    if(file.exists())
                        file.delete();
                    finish();
                    System.exit(0);        
                }
            }
            finish();
            System.exit(0);        
        }
        this.doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = true;
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please click BACK again to exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                doubleBackToExitPressedOnce=false;   

            }
        }, 2000);
    }



    private OnClickListener onClickListener = new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch(v.getId()){
            case R.id.categories_button_help:
                //DO something
                break;
            case R.id.categories_button_expand:
                Intent in = new Intent(getBaseContext(), CategoriesExpanded.class);
                //              in.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
                startActivity(in);
                finish();
                break;
            case R.id.categories_button_doksanlar:
                Intent in1 = new Intent(getBaseContext(), SelectedCategory.class);
                in1.putExtra("id", DBHelper.ID_90);
                startActivity(in1);
                break;
            case R.id.categories_button_bilim_teknoloji:
                Intent in2 = new Intent(getBaseContext(), SelectedCategory.class);
                in2.putExtra("id", DBHelper.ID_BILIM_TEKNOLOJI);
                startActivity(in2);
                break;
            case R.id.categories_button_bitkiler_alemi:
                Intent in3 = new Intent(getBaseContext(), SelectedCategory.class);
                in3.putExtra("id", DBHelper.ID_BITKILER_ALEMI);
                startActivity(in3);
                break;
            case R.id.categories_button_cizgi_filmler:
                Intent in4 = new Intent(getBaseContext(), SelectedCategory.class);
                in4.putExtra("id", DBHelper.ID_CIZGI_FILM);
                startActivity(in4);
                break;
            case R.id.categories_button_yabaci_diziler:
                Intent in5 = new Intent(getBaseContext(), SelectedCategory.class);
                in5.putExtra("id", DBHelper.ID_DIZI_YABANCI);
                startActivity(in5);
                break;
            case R.id.categories_button_yerli_diziler:
                Intent in6 = new Intent(getBaseContext(), SelectedCategory.class);
                in6.putExtra("id", DBHelper.ID_DIZI_YERLI);
                startActivity(in6);
                break;
            case R.id.categories_button_filmler:
                Intent in7 = new Intent(getBaseContext(), SelectedCategory.class);
                in7.putExtra("id", DBHelper.ID_FILM);
                startActivity(in7);
                break;
            case R.id.categories_button_hayvanlar_alemi:
                Intent in8 = new Intent(getBaseContext(), SelectedCategory.class);
                in8.putExtra("id", DBHelper.ID_HAYVANLAR_ALEMI);
                startActivity(in8);
                break;
            case R.id.categories_button_masallar:
                Intent in9 = new Intent(getBaseContext(), SelectedCategory.class);
                in9.putExtra("id", DBHelper.ID_MASAL_KAHRAMAN);
                startActivity(in9);
                break;
            case R.id.categories_button_oyunlar:
                Intent in10 = new Intent(getBaseContext(), SelectedCategory.class);
                in10.putExtra("id", DBHelper.ID_OYUNLAR);
                startActivity(in10);
                break;
            case R.id.categories_button_yabanci_sarkicilar:
                Intent in11 = new Intent(getBaseContext(), SelectedCategory.class);
                in11.putExtra("id", DBHelper.ID_SARKICILAR_YABANCI);
                startActivity(in11);
                break;
            case R.id.categories_button_yerli_sarkicilar:
                Intent in12 = new Intent(getBaseContext(), SelectedCategory.class);
                in12.putExtra("id", DBHelper.ID_SARKICILAR_YERLI);
                startActivity(in12);
                break;
            case R.id.categories_button_sehirler:
                Intent in13 = new Intent(getBaseContext(), SelectedCategory.class);
                in13.putExtra("id", DBHelper.ID_SEHIR_TR);
                startActivity(in13);
                break;
            case R.id.categories_button_siyasiler:
                Intent in14 = new Intent(getBaseContext(), SelectedCategory.class);
                in14.putExtra("id", DBHelper.ID_SIYASILER);
                startActivity(in14);
                break;
            case R.id.categories_button_sporlar:
                Intent in15 = new Intent(getBaseContext(), SelectedCategory.class);
                in15.putExtra("id", DBHelper.ID_SPOR);
                startActivity(in15);
                break;
            case R.id.categories_button_super_kahramanlar:
                Intent in16 = new Intent(getBaseContext(), SelectedCategory.class);
                in16.putExtra("id", DBHelper.ID_SUPER_KAHRAMAN);
                startActivity(in16);
                break;
            case R.id.categories_button_yabanci_tarihi_kisiler:
                Intent in17 = new Intent(getBaseContext(), SelectedCategory.class);
                in17.putExtra("id", DBHelper.ID_TARIHI_KISILER_YABANCI);
                startActivity(in17);
                break;
            case R.id.categories_button_yerli_tarihi_kisiler:
                Intent in18 = new Intent(getBaseContext(), SelectedCategory.class);
                in18.putExtra("id", DBHelper.ID_TARIHI_KISILER_YERLI);
                startActivity(in18);
                break;
            case R.id.categories_button_yabanci_tarihi_mekanlar:
                Intent in19 = new Intent(getBaseContext(), SelectedCategory.class);
                in19.putExtra("id", DBHelper.ID_TARIHI_MEKANLAR_YABANCI);
                startActivity(in19);
                break;
            case R.id.categories_button_yerli_tarihi_mekanlar:
                Intent in20 = new Intent(getBaseContext(), SelectedCategory.class);
                in20.putExtra("id", DBHelper.ID_TARIHI_MEKANLAR_YERLI);
                startActivity(in20);
                break;
            case R.id.categories_button_ulkeler:
                Intent in21 = new Intent(getBaseContext(), SelectedCategory.class);
                in21.putExtra("id", DBHelper.ID_ULKELER);
                startActivity(in21);
                break;
            case R.id.categories_button_unlu_sehirler:
                Intent in22 = new Intent(getBaseContext(), SelectedCategory.class);
                in22.putExtra("id", DBHelper.ID_UNLU_SEHIRLER);
                startActivity(in22);
                break;
            case R.id.categories_button_unluler:
                Intent in23 = new Intent(getBaseContext(), SelectedCategory.class);
                in23.putExtra("id", DBHelper.ID_UNLULER);
                startActivity(in23);
                break;
            case R.id.categories_button_yemekler:
                Intent in24 = new Intent(getBaseContext(), SelectedCategory.class);
                in24.putExtra("id", DBHelper.ID_YEMEKLER);
                startActivity(in24);
                break;
            case R.id.categories_button_cizgi_film_kahraman:
                Intent in25 = new Intent(getBaseContext(), SelectedCategory.class);
                in25.putExtra("id", DBHelper.ID_CIZGI_FILM_KAHRAMANLARI);
                startActivity(in25);
                break;
            case R.id.categories_button_karisik:
                Intent in26 = new Intent(getBaseContext(), SelectedCategory.class);
                in26.putExtra("id", DBHelper.ID_KARISIK);
                startActivity(in26);
                break;
            }

        }
    };
}
```

Comment: How big (height x width) is this drawable: @drawable/yerli_tarihi_mekanlar ?

Comment: 250x250 all buttons on that layer

Comment: Let me guess - every button has different graphics, right? No wonder you get OOM error. You have to try totally different approach (like using ListView with View Holder pattern f.e. with custom arrayadapter containing your buttons).

First create custom class ButtonSomething which would contain drawableId and ID that you're using while creating those intents. An d then you can pass that to your ArrayAdapter and display it properly.